# Xcode 6 (non-app store) Hangs When Creating New Simulator

Tags: xcode, xcode6, dmg

After upgrading to the latest release version of Xcode (7.0), I was made aware that further work by me was needed on an older project that is still being developed in Xcode 6.x/Swift 1.2. I downloaded Xcode 6.4 as a dmg from Apple's developer site (the Mac AppStore only installs Xcode 7.0 now), and installed it side-by-side by choosing "keep both" and changing the name from "Xcode 2" to "Xcode 6".

The first time I opened my project and tried to run it on the simulator, I got an alert saying that "Could not connect to simulator" or something similar (didn't write down the exact wording). I had to force-quit both Xcode and the simulator, then relaunched.

This time, I can not select any simulator from the pull down menu beside the schemes. I checked "Window / Devices" and it turns out **there is no simulator installed**.

If I click on "Add" (+), specify the properties of the simulator and then click "Create", then **Xcode hangs and I have to force-quit it** again.

Anyone experiencing something similar?

Comment: "and installed it side-by-side by choosing "keep both" and changing the name from "Xcode 2" to "Xcode 6"." In my experience, that is a _really_ bad idea. Keep its actual name (Xcode) and keep it in a folder. Might not having anything to do with the problem, but renaming Xcode can certainly cause problems. I do it this way and I have _no_ difficulty flipping back and forth between Xcode 7 and earlier versions.

Comment: Well, that is an interesting advice. So far, I have had no problems with my current approach, but I guess it doesn't hurt to install non-current versions at  `/Applications/Xcode (version)/Xcode.app`. Thanks. By the way, I also have the 7.1 beta installed right now...

Comment: Except that I also try not to put it in a folder whose name has a space in it. I've been burned by that one in the past too... :)

Comment: I could go full-unix and call it `xcode_6_4` (notice the lower case). I have a feeling I have been a lot luckier than you.

Comment: I go back to the original Xcode in OS X 10.0. I've seen it all... :(

Comment: I tried to learn Carbon back then, as a hobby, but didn't stick to it. Next time I launched Xcode was in 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about it, **after restarting my mac, it solved itself**: all the simulators are there in the pull-down menu.

Always quick-to-post me...